# I'm trying to compile a query to cope with the no rows found, but using SELECT CASE blocks bindargs

Tags: android, sqlite, conditional-statements

with a simple query, using bindargs works fine, but as soon as I include select case ..... in the query it always fails "Can't pass bindargs for this sql", if I test with all the '?'s replaced with fixed values, it compiles and runs OK, so it does seem to be that argument binding cannot cope with selects embedded inside select case. Is this true?

the query I am compiling is:

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ((SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=? AND y=?) IS NULL ) THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=? AND y=? LIMIT 1))
```

and the table is setup with

```
create table if not exists point2D ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
x REAL, y REAL )
```

I only want a single compiled query that returns the key to an existing matching record, or a known 'its not there' value, but of course a simple query like

```
SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=? AND y=? LIMIT 1
```

will cause an exception with simpleQueryForLong when there is nothing found (which is quite expensive in cpu time)

I cannot use insert or update, because update actually replaces the old row with a new row (and hence a new _id) which screws up all the other stuff pointing to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept the actual parameter code a secret, but I'd guess that you provide only two parameters although the query has four.

You can use one parameter multiple times if you give it [a name or a number](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ((SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=?1 AND y=?2) IS NULL ) THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=?1 AND y=?2 LIMIT 1))
```

However, for this particular query, you'd better use the [ifnull function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
(SELECT ifnull((SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=? AND y=?), 0))
```

(And I doubt that the outer subquery is actually needed.)

Comment: Well I did pass in all 4, hadn't come across varparam.  It still didn't like the params, but removing the outer brackets looks to have fixed it....

Comment: This is the version that works - thanks CL.
SELECT ifnull((SELECT _id FROM point2D WHERE x=? AND y=?), 0)

just got to try and make it a bit faster now...